# Gradient formula for Clarke's generalized gradient on a general Banach space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, convex-analysis

In [Theorem 10.27](https://books.google.com/books?id=1d5HAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA208&lpg=PA208&dq=10.27%20Theorem.%20(Gradient%20formula&source=bl&ots=zmqV4uS2wF&sig=ACfU3U05jXx36kFmT_t0l0WIUVcXKmbW0Q&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwih94Xj4t7kAhWSIlAKHRQCBYcQ6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=10.27%20Theorem.%20(Gradient%20formula&f=false) of the book *Functional Analysis, Calculus of Variations and Optimal Control*, there is the following gradient formula:

[image: gradient formula]

($\operatorname{co}$ deotes the convex hull).

> Is there an analogue of this result for functions $f:X\to\mathbb R$ on a general Banach (or at least Hilbert) space $X$ and the Fréchet derivative?

Here are the relevant definitions:

[image: generalized gradient]

Comment: Have you tried adapting the proof of the said Theorem?